# forming a subquery inside mysql?

Tags: mysql, subquery

List the customer number, customer name, and sales rep that have the same rep number as customer number 282.  This will need to be a subquery and do not test for sales rep 35 explicitly. Let MySQL do the work for you.   Insert your query and results here.

```
  use premier_products;

  select customer.customer_num,customer.customer_name,rep.first_name
  (SELECT rep_num
   from rep,customer
   where rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num
   and customer_num = 282)
    from customer,rep;
```

im confused with how to form a subquery with the following question. the only two fileds that are related between the two tables is rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num.

AND REP.FIRST_NAME REFERS TO SALES REP...

Comment: I’m just trying to get help , I know I’m close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study about [tables Join in MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Your query doesn't need a subquery:

```
SELECT customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, rep.first_name, rep.rep_num
FROM rep
JOIN customer
ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num
WHERE customer_num = 282;
```

Comment: Yes but I’m required to put it in a sub query  so was trying to understand how to do it that way @eventHandler

Comment: Do you know how to place this in a sub query format